# ARKit – Why there's no 'ARPlaneDetection' Enum anymore?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit

Why Apple's software engineers did remove `ARPlaneDetection` **enum** and made `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.PlaneDetection` **struct** instead?

Was:

```
public enum ARPlaneDetection: UInt {
    case .none
    case .horizontal
}
```

Now:

```
public struct PlaneDetection: OptionSet {
    public init(rawValue: UInt)
    public var horizontal: ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.PlaneDetection { get }
    public var vertical: ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.PlaneDetection { get }
}
```

What advantages does new `PlaneDetection` **struct** have over obsolete `ARPlaneDetection` **enum** in ARKit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all is because `PlaneDetection` struct conforms to [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset) protocol which allows you to set multiple options for some settings like this plane detection

```
let options: ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.PlaneDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
let options: ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.PlaneDetection = []
```

... this is advantage of `OptionSet` and this simply isn't possible with just enum.